# any topics that are researched more thoroughly

Tags: sentence-meaning, paraphrasing

What does the following sentence mean? Does it involve a contradiction?

> The present thesis could not tackle any topics that are researched more thoroughly elsewhere.

Does it mean:

If x is a topic that is researched more thoroughly elsewhere, the present thesis could not tackle x?

Comment: That is what it appears to mean, at least literally.  But that’s a rather odd idea.  Perhaps the author wanted to express something else.  Can you share any additional context?

Comment: Thank you. In what way do you find it odd?

Comment: Because the mere fact that someone else has researched a topic doesn't normally prevent it from being tackled in a thesis.  You might say "this thesis does not tackle" (that is I choose not to discuss those topics)  Because you can tackle them but choose not to.

Comment: To put a finer (and less well-put) point on what James was saying, the logic of the statement, if teased out, would suggest that the writer was not able to write about any subject unless the writer was able to research the subject more thoroughly than anyone else.  In other words, *I will only write about something that I know more about than anyone else*.  That's not a crazy idea (though it is unusual) - except that it's not really *I **will** not*, it's *I **can**not*.  Why were they unable?  Ego too big?  Thesis advisor too demanding?  It's odd.

Comment: My guess is that the author probably meant something more like this: *I did not have the space to discuss these other topics; but that's just as well, because they've already been written about by other people who are more knowledgeable than I am*.